# How to set up gef3d on eclipse

Tags: eclipse-gef

I wanted to know the installation procedure for GEF3D on eclipse. I searched through the internet but couldn't find an appropriate way to do so. Please give me the link of any site which explains the procedure and also have links to the required files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://wiki.eclipse.org/GEF3D_Installation, if you still have trouble, post your question to the GEF3D Eclipse forum.

Answer (score 0):

The installation details are listed in the GEF3D wiki on Eclipse: http://wiki.eclipse.org/GEF3D_Installation

There is no update site yet, but the project set contains every source needed.

Comment: hi,I am done with these steps of installation but I am still unknown of how to start using it. My eclipse now consists of all the folders of draw3d, draw3dgeometry,graphics3d and many others its still giving me errors in folder 'org.eclipse.gef3d.gmf' for the java class 'GMFNotatationAdapter.java' at the following line        import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject; because there is no structure like this.

Comment: I am afraid that I directory structure on this site is not the updated one and therefore I am getting errors in the imports of various types

Comment: Have you installed EMF and GMF? The org.eclipse.gef3d.gmf project depends on these projects. Otherwise I have no real idea what may be the problem.

Comment: hi, I got over the above mentioned problem. I have some other issue now.I wanted to know whether its necessary to use an editor like AMP or some other for using GEF3D? I started with installation of AMP by following the steps given here..http://www.eclipse.org/amp/installing/updates.php

Comment: But I am still facing an error at the last step as I have described here..http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=202308&start=0&S=c51083c507e5c6a6013c6c65263a7213..Please let em know if you can help me out with this